# How can I get custom SVG paths to zoom correctly in D3?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a map that I'm rendering with D3 that includes location markers that are SVG paths. I went the SVG path route for the markers so they would scale well when the map zooms. However, I can't seem to figure out how to make that actually happen.

You can see my example code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/activeshadow/86f232f4b1ca485dfd91). Try moving or zooming the map and you'll see that the markers go away.

I *think* what might be happening is since I'm not attaching the path data to the path element when I create it, the geo path projection object doesn't know how to scale it. Not sure why the location markers simply disappear when I move the map, nor do I know the proper way to attach  the data to the element. I tried passing in the path data to the `data()` method but that didn't seem to work... any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're disappearing because in your zoom function, you're selecting and re-projecting them.

The zoom method that you're using doesn't actually require you to re-project anything, you can simply do the following:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', function() {
   g.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate.join(',') + ') scale(' + d3.event.scale + ')');
   //g.selectAll('path').attr('d', path.projection(projection));
 });
```

You can see that I've commented out your select line.  Basically the `g.selectAll('path')` is selecting your markers as well.  You probably don't want to do that, since the paths are not actually projected in the first place.

Having said that, the translate/scale method of zooming (geometric zooming) doesn't require a re-projection of the paths.  See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957 and http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999 for semantic and geometric zooming examples.